# Assistance with Swift 5 WebKit and opening TEL and EMAIL links from HTML in ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

Thank you for your assistance in advance. I am hopeless stuck.

**Issue:** I am running 11.3.1 XCode and Swift 5. I have created general WKWebViews for four ViewControllers on a tabbed app. They are purely serving HTML. I cannot program a swift button from HTML obviously.

---

On Controller WebKit pages:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webViewTwo: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://berksstorage.com/beekeeper/login.html")
        webViewTwo.load(URLRequest(url: url!))

}

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }


}
```

---

**webView:** all Data detectors are selected:

[WebView Data Selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJZm.png)
`

---

**Summary:** No matter what I do, not all links open. Why? All of my button links are HTTPS.

iOS13 just completely disregards the HTML a. button links as nothing. I know the button a.  links are structured properly. I am not sure why swift will not open TEL and EMAIL button links?

Can someone explain to me why iOS13 will NOT open any TEL and EMAIL links inside the Webview? I can only assume there is a restriction somewhere. Please help!

Comment: We ran into a similar issue like this last night. I don't think we have the same problem but you might want to take a look via the developer tools in Safari, we found that the content in our web view had a main tag with some properties and it prevented the `<a>` tag inside it from being tapped by the app

Comment: Have you attempted the solution recommended or modified your code to address this problem?

Comment: @JohnAyers thanks for everything. I did attempt it. It did not work. There was some code errors and I do not have the skill level to complete the task. I appreciate all your kind and valued advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely solvable.  First though, let's dispel the notion that you cannot program a button from HTML.  If you're serving the HTML within a WKWebView, then you can capture for the click links when they occur.  Here's how:

1) Create a class object that conforms to `WKNavigationDelegate`

2) Within that class, implement `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` which is a delegate prescribed function.

3) Implement as follows:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated {

       // Here you can examine properties of the link through the navigationAction object
       let request = navigationAction.request
       let urlString = request.url.absoluteURL.lowercased()

       if urlString.hasPrefix("tel") {
           //You can construct a url to then open
           let phoneUrl = // construct here
           UIApplication.shared.open(phoneUrl)
           decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel)
           return
       } else if urlString.contains("mailto:") {
           let mailUrl = // construct here
           UIApplication.shared.open(mailUrl)
           decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel)
           return
       }
    }
    print("not captured, continuing execution")
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
 }
```

4) You need to set the delegate for your WKWebView:

`yourWkWebView.navigationDelegate = theObjectThatConformsToTheDelegateInStep3`

Final Thoughts:
If you need to start the email construction process, here are some guidelines:

```
Open = message://
Start draft with recipient = mailto://TheirEmailAddress
Start draft with recipient, cc = mailto:TheirEmailAddress?cc=TheirEmailAddress
Start draft with recipient, bcc = mailto:TheirEmailAddress?bcc=TheirEmailAddress
Start draft with recipient, subject = mailto:TheirEmailAddress&subject=Your%20Subject%20Text
Start draft with recipient, body = mailto:TheirEmailAddress&body=Your%20Body%20Text
Start draft with recipient, CC, BCC, subject, body = mailto:TheirEmailAddress?cc=TheirEmailAddress?bcc=TheirEmailAddress&subject=Your%20Subject%20Text&body=Your%20Body%20Text
```

If you need to open the phone app, you should be able to pass the link itself. iOS is looking for something that starts with `tel://` or `telprompt://`

This site does a good job keeping up-to-date with the URL schemes that Apple uses:

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

Comment: Is this not valid in Swift 5.5?  Didn't see a lowercased() option and hasPrefix isn't an option with urlString.

Comment: @John the absoluteURL property is a string. Both “lowercased()” and “hasPrefix” are part of the Swift standard library for strings.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641392-lowercased  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix